# Applying styles to a <video> when not in fullscreen mode

Tags: html, css, video

I'd like to apply a style to a `<video>` only when it's not in fullscreen mode. My first thought was:

```css
video:not(:fullscreen):not(:-webkit-full-screen):not(:-moz-full-screen):not(:-ms-fullscreen) {}
```

Unfortunately, MDN [states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) that `not()` must not contain pseudo elements.

I'd like to have the browser's default style take over in fullscreen mode, while I handle positioning of the element in non-fullscreen. I'm sure it's possible to do with adding a class through JS in fullscreen, but are there css-only ways to do it?

Comment: Those are psuedo-classes, not pseudo-elements.

Comment: You're right. It does seem to take :fullscreen, at least when splitting up the selectors: http://jsfiddle.net/silverwind/s5Ln3k44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser will completely ignore any selector that contains an unrecognized part (such as a prefixed pseudo-class from a different browser).

Therefore, you need to split each browser version into a separate ruleset.

Comment: Yeah, thats it. Thanks!